# How to get a list of users based on the radius?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, users, entities

I want to allow users (workers) to give their address using [addressfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield) and also give a distance or radius they are prepared to travel. It is a job site. When a client posts a job (node) and provides address, the clients must see a list of users (workers) who might be the potential candidates.

Obviously there will be taxonomy terms as well like interest, experience etc, but my question is about allowing a user to provide address and radius and then matching them with the node posted by the client and if the user falls within the address provided by the client, the client must see a list of users who will be available for the job in the area.

How should I go about it? What should be my approach?

Please clarify if there is confusion.

Comment: Use case of documentation provided here is different from your use case but you can implement your idea by reading this doc. [Basic Dealer Locator, User Locator, Store Locator proximity search](https://www.drupal.org/node/1944648)

Comment: @yogesh.kushwaha I have read it before, but I am wondering how I can use it for my case. May you can share your thoughts